# Automatically concatenating files using Watchr

Tags: ruby, node.js, rubygems, watchr

I have a bunch of JS files that I split up, but want to concatenate automatically (so I don't define a bunch of files in HTML). Right now, I copied the command from Twitter Bootstrap. Makefile:

```
scripts:
 cat scripts/*.js > public/scripts/scripts.js

watchScripts: 
  watchr -e "watch('scripts/.*\.js') {system 'make scripts'}"
```

However, I've found `watchr` to be very inconsistent (on Mac OS X 10.8)

1. Sometimes when I save a `js` file, it doesn't run `make scripts`. Other times, it does.
2. One time, it just kept running `make scripts` continuously after a single save.
3. Sometimes, it will run the command a few seconds after the last save.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm working using `node.js` and not `Ruby`, so are there any `node.js` command-line alternatives? The same issues seem to happen to me when I try `make watch` in Bootstrap.

Aside question: I have another watch command:

```
stylus -w -u nib styles/styles.styl -o public/styles
```

How can I run two watch commands in a single Makefile command? IE `make watch` will watch both `.styl` files to compile, and `.js` files to concatenate. Right now I'm opening up two terminals, for each watch command, but I'd prefer a single one.

Comment: installed `gem install rev` as told by `https://github.com/mynyml/watchr/` and it seems to fix the problem.

Comment: +1. So, to `make watch` in Bootstrap, are we supposed to use _watchr_ for Node.js or gem?

_watchr_ for Node.js: _https://github.com/bevry/watchr_
_watchr_ for gem: _https://github.com/mynyml/watchr_

Comment: I installed _watchr_ `gem install watchr` and also `gem install rev`, `gem install ruby-fsevent` but `make watch` didn't do anything when there was a change in one of the LESS files. I was on Mac OS X 10.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [brunch](http://brunch.io/)? It's really great for this kind of stuff when working on node.js. You can just use a skeleton or set it up manually and have a script your whole directory, merging and compiling on the go.

Comment: this seems overly complicated and large for what i need (just concatenating js files). i don't understand why they feel it is necessary to install basically everything with brunch.

Comment: plus, why is it written in coffeescript?

Comment: Basically any advanced watcher process is a quite complicated thing. For example, it needs to preserve user’s script order even if user uses different languages (stylus, css, sass, less), it needs to able to lint or auto-wrap files in modules etc etc. Brunch makes stuff just work, but if you have really small project I guess it will be better to manually set up stuff.

As for CoffeeScript, it gives a lot cleaner code, especially if you prefer functional paradigm.